German made-for-TV movie about terrorists threatening to blow up a nuclear reactor with a fuel-air bomb?
I am trying to find back the reference to an old german TV movie (back from the mid-80s or so) with the following 24-like scenario. 
Note that these were the times when nuclear reactors (especially fast breeders) were scary in Germany, mobile phones didn't exist, and Germany was regulary hit bombs set up by red or brown extremists.
So here it is. Spoilers, of course:

Phone call comes in at the Ministry of Interior threatening to blow up a nuclear reactor; for this not to occur, a load of gold has got to be dropped into a lake within 48h or so.
The nuclear reactor is supposed to be done in using a Fuel-Air bomb, presumably to be dropped from a plane.
I remember the FAE blueprint (really in white on blue) shown on an overhead projector.
In order to prove the seriousness of the threats, a nuclear reactor has already received a "drop from the air" treatement - with a paint bomb, leaving a huge red blotch on the concrete cupola.
Female journalist see the blotch, decides to investigate, while the authorities are keeping the lid on the whole affair.
She manages to scare up a group of Nazi goons which she supposes are behind it all.
Some killings ensue.
Authorities can't find the perps. As the threat is believable, they lose the nerve, and decide to do the golddrop.
Our journalistic heroine has found out where the drop is supposed to happen and shows up in time. 
At the scene, she meets an old guy who confesses that he is behind the whole stunt. It was just to show that nuclear energy is unsafe (or something). 
As the gold is plunging into the lake from a Transall, she ask how he is going to recuperate the loot. The answer is "I have no intention to".
Conspiracy guy hands her all the conspiracy good, blueprints and documents so that she can do the story.
As she comes home, the nazi goons catch up with her and kill her.
The last scene shows the goons handing the infostash to their leader. "We found this at her place...". 
The leader goes like "Woah... that's pretty interesting!"


Sounds like the German TV movie Gambit from 1987, in which terrorists threaten the government that they'll bomb a nuclear plant and demand one billion Deutschmarks in gold, and a female journalist investigates this story. There's more info (and pics) in this Amazon page. Here's a still from the movie with that red blotch on the plant's dome:

